# Access most recent table row and its data

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

I'm creating a small app based on the conditions of the results of the last game played, or the last row with game data (win/lose and game number).

My issue is accessing the first column of the last row (most recent game played). How is that accomplished?

[image: Data source]

```
require 'open-uri'

class BrooklynPizzaController < ApplicationController

  def index
    # URL for dynamic content
    url = "http://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/BRK/2015_games.html"

    # Open URL using nokogiri
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

    # Scrape result from Web site
    @result = doc.css("#teams_games").xpath("//table/tbody/tr/td[8]/text()")

    # IN PROGRESS - Get date of last game played
    @result_date = doc.xpath('//table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a/text()') do |link|
      @result_date[link.text.strip] = link['a']
    end


    ###############################################################
    # IN PROGRESS - Get number of last game played from 1st column
    # doc.xpath('//table/tbody/tr/td[1]/text()') do |game|
    #   last_game_number = 
    # end
    ################################################################

    # @result_date = doc.css("#teams_games").xpath("//table/tbody/tr/td[2]/text()")
    # Set date to current
    @date = Date.today

    # Get date of last game played
    if (@result.last.next == nil)
      flag = doc.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[#{@result}]")
      @result_date = doc.xpath("//table/tbody/tr#{flag}/td[2]/a/text()")
    end
  end
end
```

Please let me know what lack of information I'm giving you, because I feel like I've left out some things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the row you would do this:

```
win_loss_tds = doc.css("#teams_games tbody tr td:nth-child(8):not(:empty)").last
last_win_loss_row = win_loss_tds.last.parent
```

There's undoubtedly a way to do that in a single XPath expression, but I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader since I don't care for XPath.

To get the game number from the first column you would do this:

```
game_num_col = last_win_loss_row.at("td:first-child")
game_num = game_num_col.text.to_i
# => 82
```

And to get the date from the second column:

```
date_col = last_win_loss_row.at("td:nth-child(2)") # XPath: td[2]
date = DateTime.parse(date_col.text)
# => 2015-04-15T00:00:00+00:00
```

If you want date and time, you could do this:

```
time_col = last_win_loss_row.at("td:nth-child(3)")
date_time = DateTime.parse("#{date_col.text} #{time_col.text}")
# => 2015-04-15T08:00:00-03:00
```

Comment: `last_row` should be referring to row x (in this case, denoted as row/game 13 in the image), the last, most recent row with a W or L (flag) in column 8 and not the last row in the entire table.

Comment: It's not necessary to use `at_css` (or `css`) unless the selector is ambiguous and could be confused with XPath. The shorter `at` (or `search`) will usually do the right thing. Also, if speed is important, `parse` is a lot slower than specifying the date format and using `strptime`.

Comment: @theTinMan Thanks for the tips. Considering how much time fetching and parsing each page will take, I suspect the `DateTime.parse` overhead will be inconsequential, but it's a good tip anyway.

Comment: @Jordan The only issue with your answer was the `last` method here: `win_loss_tds = doc.css("#teams_games tbody tr td:nth-child(8):not(:empty)").last` I removed that and my code runs clean.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'd do this:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/BRK/2015_games.html"))

latest_score_row = doc.search('//tr/td/a[contains(.,"Box Score")]/../..').last
latest_text = latest_score_row.search('td').map(&:text)
# => ["13",
#     "Sat, Nov 22, 2014",
#     "8:30p EST",
#     "",
#     "Box Score",
#     "@",
#     "San Antonio Spurs",
#     "L",
#     "",
#     "87",
#     "99",
#     "5",
#     "8",
#     "L 1",
#     ""]
```

But YMMV.

---

How does it work? Easy. It looks for `<a>` nodes in the page containing "Box Score", then, for each one found, backs up two levels to the `<tr>` node and returns an array to Nokogiri/Ruby. `last` takes the last one found.

Then it's just a matter of looking in that row for the `<td>` nodes and grabbing their text.

The time stamp is then a matter of pulling the date and time from the array, doing a tiny bit of massaging of the "am/pm" and letting Ruby build an object:

```
latest_time = Time.strptime(             
  [
    latest_text[1],                      # => "Sat, Nov 22, 2014"
    latest_text[2].sub(/([ap])/, '\1m')  # => "8:30pm EST"
  ].join(' '),                           # => "Sat, Nov 22, 2014 8:30pm EST"
  '%a, %b %d, %Y %H:%M%P %Z'             # => "%a, %b %d, %Y %H:%M%P %Z"
)                                        # => 2014-11-22 18:30:00 -0700
```